# Motorboat noise from toilet, then shower

Tags: shower, toilet, noise

Flushed the toilet in the MB and it made a foghorn noise until the water shut off.  I replaced the flush valve.

I turned the water off at the entry and drained all the lines. Water on.  Then, with all faucets, etc. open a little, began turning them off one at a time, beginning with those in the basement, in order to push out all air in the system.

The next day the noise returned - but - the noise is now emanating from around the shower valve several feet away.  Flush the toilet and get a noise from the shower (off).  This happens about 1 in 20 flushes.

I turned the water off at the entry and drained all the lines. Water on.  Then, with all faucets, etc. open a little, began turning them off one at a time, beginning with those in the basement, in order to push out all air in the system.

Plumber checked water pressure and it is fine at 61 lbs.  Expansion tank on water heater is fine.  Water hammer reducer chambers on both hot and cold faucets in the nearby laundry room.  Naturally, it would not happen while the plumber was here.

Any ideas?  Think I will replace the flush valve again, different brand.

Comment: how would you get air in your system, from where ?

Comment: @Ruskes - You get air in the system when you drain it.

Answer (score 0):

You might need one of those Automatic air release valves, like they use on central heating.

Best location would be at highest water pipe in your home.

Comment: All fixed !!!  Plumber measured the pressure at 60 and he said it was fine.  I bought a pressure gauge and it measured 64-66.  Turned the pressure down to 56 and the problem disappeared.    I noticed that his gauge appeared to have seen its best days.

Comment: I would have left it until halloween is over! :-) It appears you have it fixed, I would not worry about it.